# 2D DWT computation order

Tags: image-processing, matlab, wavelet, jpeg, dwt

In 2D the [discrete wavelet transform (DWT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) of an image using lifting based 5/3 filter, if I perform a row-wise operation first then perform column-wise operation then I will get 4 sub-band LL, LH and HL and HH.

- During reconstruction, that is IDWT, should I maintain the order in reverse direction that is column first and then row?
- Or any order I can maintain?
- In JPEG 2000 there is no order information found in the header. Then how I can main the order during reconstruction?

Answer (score 1):

For each single level of a isotropic or square DWT, the row/column order is not important.  Note however that there exists an alternative decomposition, termed anisotropic, rectangular, that does all rows first, then all columns (or the converse) which results in a different subband organization. This is described in the overview of 2D wavelets: [A panorama on Multiscale Geometric Representations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.sigpro.2011.04.025) ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5320)) in Section 3: 2.3.2. Separable orthogonal wavelets.

[EDIT: Added references to related questions]

- [2D DWT Image Issue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/25601/15892)
- [What is the correct order of operations for a 2D Haar wavelet decomposition?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58843/what-is-the-correct-order-of-operations-for-a-2d-haar-wavelet-decomposition/58864#58864)
- [2D DWT computation order](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37092/15892)

Comment: Thanks you sir. But in MATLAB simulation i found that: when I am doing DWT(using 5/3 le gal filter) of an image first row wise then column wise and get 4 sub-bands. My doubt is in IDWT process, when I perform just reverse order of DWT process, that is column first and then row we get exact reconstruction, but if i perform first rowwise reconstruction and then column wise we are not getting proper reconstruction. What is the resion?

Comment: Please help me to share my code. I cannot add here because it is toolong.