# discrete wavelet transform matrix for vectorized image

Tags: dwt

Yesterday I asked about how to extract 2D DFT matrix for a vectorized image. Today my question is how can I extract 2D DWT matrix for a vectorized image. 
Fourier transform have this property that rows of the image are transformed first, than columns are transformed. Is there a similiar property for discrete wavelet transform such that 1D DWT matrix can be utilized for 2D DWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only one level on both direction, the classical DWT schemes are applied separately (rows then columns, or colums then rows).

For more levels, there exist two schemes:

- one interleaving decompositions: row, col, row, col, etc. (also called non-separable/square/non-standard/isotropic/Mallat),
- one on all rows, then all colums (also called separable/rectangle/standard/anisotropic/tensor).

The second one only deserves the "fully separable" mention.

References to related questions:

- [2D DWT Image Issue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/25601/15892)
- [What is the correct order of operations for a 2D Haar wavelet decomposition?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58843/what-is-the-correct-order-of-operations-for-a-2d-haar-wavelet-decomposition/58864#58864)
- [2D DWT computation order](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37092/15892)